Google App Script recursive Loop does not trigger prompt.getResponseText()
I made the following script to identify names that were not matching between two files. This works perfectly fine for the first loop, and it gets to the var prompt perfectly fine on the second loop, however whenever I try to complete the prompt on sheets it seemingly does nothing and just stalls there. It is not because of the input because if I do that input the first time it goes through fine. I must be missing something as to why this isn't looping properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated


function onEdit(e) {
    startPoint();
    
}

function startPoint(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("README");
    var cell = "N5";
    var difference = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue().toFixed(2);

    if (difference > 0){
      yesDifference(difference);
    }else noDifference(difference);
}

function yesDifference(num){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    const result = ui.alert(
     'There is a difference of: ' + 
     num
      + '\nWould you like to solve the issue',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)
    if (result == ui.Button.YES){
      findDifference(num);
    }else{
      return
    }
}

function noDifference(num){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    const result = ui.alert(
     'Tips are matching!');
    return
}

function findDifference(num){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("README");
  var missingNames = sheet.getRange("Z3:Z20").getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < missingNames.length; i++){
      var person = missingNames[i].toString();
      if(person.length > 1){
        const result = ui.alert(
          'I am not able to match:\n' + person + '\nbetween Harri and R365 would you like to try and find them?',
          ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
        if(result == ui.Button.YES){
          findNameMatch(person);
        }
      }
  }
    return
}

function findNameMatch(name){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("README");

  var allNames = sheet.getRange("A2:A100").getValues();
  var filteredNames = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++){
    var person = allNames[i].toString();
    if(!(person.length > 1)){
      i = allNames.length;
    }else{
      if(!(filteredNames.includes(person))){
        filteredNames.push(person);
      } 
    }
  }

  var prompt = ui.prompt('Out of the following names:\n\n\n' + filteredNames.join('\r\n') + "\n\n\nPlease enter below which name is supposed to be " + name);

  var fullName = prompt.getResponseText().toString();

  var resp = ui.alert(fullName);

  var firstName = fullName.substring(0, fullName.indexOf(' '));
  var lastName = fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(' ') + 1);

  var originalFirst = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(' '));
  var originalLast = name.substring(fullName.indexOf(' ') + 1);

  var names = ui.alert(
    'First Name: ' + firstName + "\nLast Name: " + lastName
  )

  changeName(originalFirst, firstName, originalLast, lastName);
  startPoint();
}

function changeName(oldF, correctF, oldL, correctL){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("365");
  var allFNames = sheet.getRange("A2:A100").getValues();
  var allLNames = sheet.getRange("B2:B100").getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < allFNames.length; i++){
    var name = allFNames[i].toString();
    var lastName = allLNames[i].toString();
    if(!(name.length > 1)){
      i = allFNames.length;
    }else{
      if((name === oldF) &&(lastName === oldL)){
        var newFirst = "A" + (i + 2);
        var newLast = "B" + (i + 2);

        var newFNames = sheet.getRange(newFirst).setValue(correctF);
        var newLNames = sheet.getRange(newLast).setValue(correctL);

        const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        const result = ui.alert(
        'The names have been changed at ' + newFirst + ", and " + newLast + " to " + correctF + ", and " + correctL);
        i = allFNames.length;
      }
    }
  }
  return
}



I have created a spreadsheet with minimal data in it to recreate the issue. On the R365 Sheet if you edit one of the names it should trigger the function the same way
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uLOghTaxPURScAsAvwhyPZpmaVh5P7o7E4c88gwn9a4/edit?gid=160981461#gid=160981461

Please provide minimal reproducible example.

What recursion?

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand whenever I try to complete the prompt on sheets it seemingly does nothing and just stalls there. Can I ask you about the details? First, I would like to understand your question correctly.

FYI: var originalLast = name.substring(fullName.indexOf(' ') + 1); should read var originalLast = name.substring(name.indexOf(' ') + 1);

function findNameMatch(name): delete line#91 startPoint();

function changeName(oldF, correctF, oldL, correctL){ change  if((name === oldF) &&(lastName === oldL)){ to if((name !== oldF) &&(lastName !== oldL)){

If you make these three changes, the script will loop as expected. I am not altogether satisfied that changename is working as expected (in terms of the rows updated on sheet "365") but... Since you have not (yet) supplied sample data and examples of successful outcomes, I'm unable to say whether these concerns are justified.

@Wiimm  var difference =  ... assigns a string. True. So if (difference > 0) makes a text comparison. False. Doc Ref. In general terms, JavaScript will convert the string to a number when comparing a string with a number.

@user27425627
maybe recursion wasn't the correct term in this instance but these functions should continuously repeat until the difference in start() are not > 0

@Tedinoz
The changeName is working as expected I think my variable naming in this instance was subpar, the problem is in the second time around it doesn't even get to the changename function, the last thing it does is the prompt, but does not do the alert right after

If I get rid of start() it does not loop and ask to check again

@Lime Husky
I have added a link in the question to a minimal example

var allNames = sheet.getRange("A2:A100").getValues(); If a name from "allNames" is chosen to be updated, then shouldn't that name in Column A be deleted (and the rows resorted) so that the name is not available for future loops/instances of onEdit?

startPoint: I suggest a line such as if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "README" && e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.range.columnStart == 14 ){ to avoid execution of the script for EVERY edit.

I'm getting Exceeded maximum execution time for onEdit. I suggest that you rename onEdit to, say nameUpdate and create a installable onEdit trigger.

@Tedinoz Thank you for the suggestions, I actually added the second suggestion on the original sheet and forgot to update it on this one and it certainly does help ALOT. However I am still unable to notice a flawless execution. On this sheet currently it works for the first 2 times then stops after the third. Would you care to point me in the right direction of a installable onEdit trigger I can't seem to find any info on what that is vs what I am doing

@Tedinoz So there are certain instances that a name should be chosen more than once, there have been occasions where the same person has different spellings multiple times (User Error but it does happen), so it is not often but it is possible for a name inside of allNames to be chosen more than once as the "solution"

CORRECTION function changeName(oldF, correctF, oldL, correctL){ change if((name === oldF) &&(lastName === oldL)){ to if((name !== oldF) &&(lastName !== oldL)){ This is wrong - please ignore

You want to update name of customers that aren't being matched with existing data but your loop is not working.
Consider this answer:
Differences

'onEdit(e)` is a Simple trigger and is timing out maximum execution time.

Change the function name name from onEdit(e) to something else, say, updateNames(e)
Create an Installable onEdit trigger for the new function name.
If you don't change the function name, then there is a risk that the function will execute twice - once as an Installable trigger and once as Simple trigger. The result is confusing and promotes error.


make use of Event Objects.

insert Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) immediately after updateNames(e).

This will display the available Event Objects


change startPoint(e) and function startPoint(e){


In startpoint(e) include a test for sheet, column and row, such as:
if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "README" && e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.range.columnStart == 14 ){

this will ensure that unrelated edits can be made without invoking the entire function


error in var originalLast = name.substring(fullName.indexOf(' ') + 1);

change to var originalLast = name.substring(name.indexOf(' ') + 1);


delete startPoint(); from the last line of function findNameMatch(name){

The loop relies on for(var i = 0; i < missingNames.length; i++){ in function findDifference
returning to startPoint() restarts the entire function rather than allowing the "for" loop to play out.


A number of Logger statements have been included to track the values of variables, and the progress of routines. These slow processing and the OP may wish to display those that appear helpful at any point in time.

It is not clear whether the value in Column M on sheet "365" should be updated with the "difference".



function updateNames(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  startPoint(e);
    
}

function startPoint(e){
  // test for edited sheet and column and row
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "README" && e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.range.columnStart == 14 ){ // cell 'N5"
    // edit is in correct place, continue processing 
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: edit was in N5 on Readme - continue processing")
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("README");
    var cell = "N5";
    var difference = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue().toFixed(2);
    if (difference > 0){
      yesDifference(difference);
    }else{
       noDifference(difference);
    }
  }
  else{
    // edit is NOT in correct place, stop processing 
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: edit was NOT N5 on Readme - stop processing")
    return
  }
}

function yesDifference(num){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    const result = ui.alert(
     'There is a difference of: ' + 
     num
      + '\nWould you like to solve the issue',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)
    if (result == ui.Button.YES){
      // solve the difference
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: solve the difference")
      findDifference(num);
    }else{
      // do nothing
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Do nothing")
      return
    }
}

function noDifference(num){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    const result = ui.alert(
     'Tips are matching!');
    return
}

function findDifference(num){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("README");
  var missingNames = sheet.getRange("Z3:Z20").getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < missingNames.length; i++){
      var person = missingNames[i].toString();
      if(person.length > 1){
        const result = ui.alert(
          'I am not able to match:\n' + person + '\nbetween Harri and R365 would you like to try and find them?',
          ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
        if(result == ui.Button.YES){
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: the name of the person is "+person)
          findNameMatch(person);
        }
      }
  }
    return
}

function findNameMatch(name){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("README");

  var allNames = sheet.getRange("A2:A100").getValues();
  var filteredNames = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < allNames.length; i++){
    var person = allNames[i].toString();
    if(!(person.length > 1)){
      i = allNames.length;
    }else{
      if(!(filteredNames.includes(person))){
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: filtered names doesn't include "+person+", so person added to filtered names")
        filteredNames.push(person);
      } 
    }
  }

  var prompt = ui.prompt('Out of the following names:\n\n\n' + filteredNames.join('\r\n') + "\n\n\nPlease enter below which name is supposed to be " + name);

  var fullName = prompt.getResponseText().toString();

  var resp = ui.alert(fullName);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: name chosen for findNameMatch = "+fullName)
  var firstName = fullName.substring(0, fullName.indexOf(' '));
  var lastName = fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(' ') + 1);

  var originalFirst = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(' '));
  var originalLast = name.substring(name.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: findNameMatch: first name = "+firstName+", last name = "+lastName+", Original first  = "+originalFirst+", Original last = "+originalLast)
  var names = ui.alert(
    'First Name: ' + firstName + "\nLast Name: " + lastName
  )

  changeName(originalFirst, firstName, originalLast, lastName);
  
}

function changeName(oldF, correctF, oldL, correctL){
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: changename: oldF = "+oldF+", correct F = "+correctF+", oldL = "+oldL+", correct L = "+correctL)
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("365");
  var allFNames = sheet.getRange("A2:A100").getValues();
  var allLNames = sheet.getRange("B2:B100").getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < allFNames.length; i++){
    var name = allFNames[i].toString();
    var lastName = allLNames[i].toString();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: changeName: i:"+i+", name:"+name+", last name:"+lastName+", name length:"+name.length)
    if(!(name.length > 1)){
      i = allFNames.length;
    }else{
      if((name === oldF) &&(lastName === oldL)){
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: name <> old F and last name <> oldL")
        var newFirst = "A" + (i + 2);
        var newLast = "B" + (i + 2);
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: cells: newFirst:"+newFirst+", newlast:"+newLast)
        var newFNames = sheet.getRange(newFirst).setValue(correctF);
        var newLNames = sheet.getRange(newLast).setValue(correctL);
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Updated newfirst and newlast with correctF and correctL")
        const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        const result = ui.alert(
        'The names have been changed at ' + newFirst + ", and " + newLast + " to " + correctF + ", and " + correctL);
        i = allFNames.length;
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: i is set to allFnames length: "+i)
      }else{
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: if unsuccessful")
      }
    }
  }
  return
}


SAMPLE DATA - sheet "Harri" before

SAMPLE DATA  - sheet "365: before

SAMPLE DATA - Person 2


SAMPLE DATA - Person 4


SAMPLE DATA - sheet "365" after

SAMPLE - sheet" Readme" after


Sorry for how long it took me to try this. The trigger worked perfectly, I greatly appreciate your help!
